# Rearrange this expression for lambda and substitute it back into the expression

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to rearrange this expression for $\lambda$ and substitute it back into the expression for $\mathbf{r}'$ in order to get $\mathbf{r}'$ in terms of $\mathbf{r}$:

### $\mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3 + \lambda s_3 = 0$  (where $s_3 = \hat{\mathbf{s}}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3$)

I worked out $\lambda = - \mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3/s_3$

I then had to substitute the solved $\lambda$ into the following expression:

### $\mathbf{r}' = \mathbf{r} + \lambda \hat{\mathbf{s}}$

Which is solved by doing the following:

$\mathbf{r}' = r + \hat{\mathbf{s}} (- \mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3/s_3)$

$\mathbf{r}' = r - \hat{\mathbf{s}} (\mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3)/s_3$

I get confused at the last step. Why does the minus get swapped out and $\mathbf r + \hat{\mathbf{s}}$ become $\mathbf r - \hat{\mathbf{s}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the expressions correctly. There is no $r + \hat{\mathbf{s}}$ or $r - \hat{\mathbf{s}}$. In the original expression, the $\hat{\mathbf{s}}$ is multiplied by $\lambda$, *then* the result is added to $r$.  So after the substitution, it becomes

$$ \mathbf{r}' = r + \left(\hat{\mathbf{s}} (- \mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3/s_3) \right)$$

I inserted extra parentheses to emphasize where the confusion may be. The above is then equal to

$$ \mathbf{r}' = r - \left(\hat{\mathbf{s}} (\mathbf{r}.\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3/s_3) \right)$$

Comment: Yes  thank you! Not enough sleep.